# setInterval, ajax request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

What's the best way to fetch ajax request.

mine gets gets faster and faster everytime it calls the javascript function
i don't know why.

here's the code :

```
$(function(){
getSuggestions();
});

function getSuggestions(){
    var url = $("#baseUrl").val() + '/placement/suggestions/x-fetch-suggestions';
    var data ={}
    var result = myAjaxJson(data,url); //gets json object via ajax

/* gets object 'sug' and put into #suggestions-list*/
    $('#suggestions-list').html(result.sug);

    var a = setInterval("getSuggestions()",5000);
}
```

Comment: Please add the implementation of `myAjaxJson`

Comment: you should wait intel ajax is complete then start `setInterval`

Comment: `setInterval` will call the function repeatedly, not only once: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got sort of a recursive doubleloop there.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
   var a = setInterval("getSuggestions()",5000);
});

function getSuggestions(){
    var url = $("#baseUrl").val() + '/placement/suggestions/x-fetch-suggestions';
    var data ={}
    var result = myAjaxJson(data,url); //gets json object via ajax

/* gets object 'sug' and put into #suggestions-list*/
    $('#suggestions-list').html(result.sug);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are starting new setInterval each time you call the getSuggestions. Set it outside:

```
$(function(){
    var a = setInterval("getSuggestions()",5000);
});
```

Insteed of

```
$(function(){
    getSuggestions();
});
```

And remove the setInterval code from the getSuggestions method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use setInterval, use setTimeout. setInterval calls the function every 5 seconds regardless of whether the previous Ajax request completed. setTimeout will wait 5 seconds after the previous Ajax request to start thenext one.:

```
$(function(){
getSuggestions();
});

function getSuggestions(){
    var url = $("#baseUrl").val() + '/placement/suggestions/x-fetch-suggestions';
    var data ={}
    var result = myAjaxJson(data,url); //gets json object via ajax

/* gets object 'sug' and put into #suggestions-list*/
    $('#suggestions-list').html(result.sug);

    var a = setTimeout("getSuggestions()",5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var counter = 0;
var timer = null;
function loader(){
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
        return;
    }
    timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    $("#paragraph").load("file.php");
    }, 10);
}

window.onload = function() {
    loader();
};
```